# ActiveStorage::IntegrityError only in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, rails-activestorage, bitbucket-pipelines

On Bitbuckets pipelines, whenever I try to run a `bundle exec rspec` that contains rspec test that uses Active Storage I get the following error, for every of these tests:

```
ActiveStorage::IntegrityError:
   ActiveStorage::IntegrityError
 # ./spec/requests/api/v1/spa_clients/identity_providers/update_spec.rb:127:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/api/v1/spa_clients/identity_providers/update_spec.rb:135:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is weird since:

- If I run the tests locally everything runs smoothly;
- The same pipeline with the same pipeline image version a few days ago run without errors;

I am really struggling to get more ideas to how to find a solution.

---

Edit with answer:

Answer from the atlassian team to our contact: "Based on our investigation, we notice that the FlatcarOS upgrade (v2765.2.2) had introduced a bug that caused builds that uses Ruby/Rails or yarn/npm package to fail.". Their temp solution is to rollback to previously working solution.

Comment: I started getting the exact same issue out of no where! Would be great if somebody can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made contact with the support team and they replied me that they are aware about the issue, for now they have a temporary fix if you give you repository information.

This is the BUG:

- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21046